# Can we use Bernstein's inequality without knowledge of variance?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

I have a question about Bernstein’s inequality for bounded random variables.

Its statement is the following. Let $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ be independent, mean zero random variables with $|X_i| \leq K \ (i = 1, \ldots, N)$. Then, for any $t \geq 0$, we have
$$
P \left( \left|\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\right| \geq t \right) \leq 2 \exp\left(-\frac{t^2/2}{\sigma^2 + Kt/3}\right) 
$$
where $\sigma^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E}[X_i^2]$ (see e.g. Theorem 2.8.4 of [Vershynin's book](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html)).

If the variance $\sigma^2$ is known, we can use Bernstein’s inequality to obtain possibly a shaper bound than the Hoeffding bound (especially when $\sigma^2$ is small; see, e.g., the remark after Theorem 2.10 of [Wainwright's book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E)).

However, this inequality is not useful if we have access to only finite samples and don’t know the true variance $\sigma^2$, in the sense that we cannot directly evaluate the value of the right-hand side with the accessible samples.

In practice, if the sample variance is small and the sample size is sufficiently large, we can infer that $\sigma^2$ is small with a high probability. So it would be natural to hope to utilize such knowledge (i.e. small variance) to obtain a sharper bound than Hoeffding's bound with Bernstein's inequality.

Are there any proper ways of conducting such an idea?

Comment: Your questions are quite unclear and are impossible to answer in this form. What exactly **do** you know? And what is your goal here, specifically? Also, you should reduce your questions just to one. (There should not be multiple questions in one post.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I revised my question to clarify my point. I found a paper that provided an answer, so I answered my question myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have learned that my question was the exact idea behind the so-called *empirical Bernstein bounds*. See this paper for details:
https://www.learningtheory.org/colt2009/papers/012.pdf